# Can i combine 2 devices to get more power for mining

Tags: mining-theory

As An example lets say i have 2 USB Miners each one has 16 GH/s
can i combine these 2 to mine with 32 GH/s ?

And if yes pls tell me how.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. To do this simply mine with both at the same time. A mining pool will never give out the same work twice. So mining with two 16 GH/s devices will be the same as one 32 GH/s device.

If you mine at the same mining pool with both then the pool will show you mining at 32 GH/s.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes for USB based mining H/W hosted on the same computer. The [bfgminer and cgminer mining applications](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_software) can easily support multiple USB mining devices on the same computer.

However, the answer is no if you are mining from home behind a NAT firewall and are trying to point two or more different IPv4 based miners to the same mining pool server supporting Stratum (STM) or GetBlockTemplate (GBT) protocols. This is a NAT firewall issue.

Comment: Mining with multiple devices behind NAT works fine